# how to install grunt sass in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, sass, gruntjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use grunt in my first angular project .I am trying to use sass in my project .I follow all steps of this link
http://blog.meredithunderell.com/2014/07/24/setting-up-twitter-bootstrap-sass-with-grunt-in-an-angularjs-project/

I am trying to use sass which convert .sass file to css file .but when I run my project I am getting error this

```
MacBook-Pro:test_saas naveenkumar$ grunt sass
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning: 
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
MacBook-Pro:test_saas naveenkumar$
```

In above link it is not written this type of error or warning 
could you please tell me how to solve this error

here is my gruntfile.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        project: {
            app: ['app'],
            assets: ['<%= project.app %>/assets'],
            css: ['<%= project.assets %>/sass/style.scss']
        },sass: {

               dist:{
                   files:{
                       'app/assets/css/style.css':'app/assets/css/style.scss'
                   }
               }
            //dev: {
            //    options: {
            //        style: 'expanded'},
            //    files: {
            //        '<%= project.assets %>/css/style.css':'<%= project.css %>'
            //    }
            //}
        },watch: {
            sass: {
                files: '<%= project.assets %>/sass/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }


    });



    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'watch'
    ]);

};
```

**update**

After install sass it gives this error

```
MacBook-Pro:test_saas naveenkumar$ grunt sass
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - undefined
  Use --trace for backtrace.
Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: Do you have Sass installed?

Comment: I don't know much ..How to install sass ..i that tutorial sass install not written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's telling you *explicitly* what you're doing incorrectly.

> You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.

do you have ruby installed? do you have Sass installed? it looks like you're on a macbook so you probably have ruby already. try `gem install sass` in your terminal and see what happens.

more here: http://sass-lang.com/install

Comment: trying I will update you ..I have one Question I am working on angular not ruby so why it is giving error of Ruby and Sass

Comment: please check my update still not working it gives another error